# How to create an enum for pageControl.currentPage?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to keep track of my pages using pageControl.currentPage which returns an integer. My switch statement is set up like so:

```
let currentPage = pageControl.currentPage
switch currentPage {
case 0:

// execute code for first page 

case 1:

// execute code for second page 

case 2:

// execute code for third page 

default: break
}
```

instead of case "0", "1", and "2", I'd like to be more semantic such as

```
case FirstPage:
case SecondPage:
case ThirdPage:
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to back the enum with an `Int` value.

You can declare your enum like so:

```
enum PageEnum: Int {
  case firstPage = 0  // Implicitly 0 if you don't set value for first enum.
  case secondPage = 1 // Each enum after will automatically increase by 1
  case thirdPage = 2  // so explicitly listing raw value is not necessary.
}
```

You can then use a switch to determine the page value like so:

```
switch PageEnum(rawValue: currentPage)! {
  case .firstPage:
    print("You're on the first page")
  case .secondPage:
    print("You're on the second page")
  case .thirdPage:
    print("You're on the third page")
  default:
    assert(false, "You shouldn't ever land here")
}
```

Comment: Nice! I just learned something from this. One nice side-effect - when I tried the code the compiler warned me that the "default" case can never be reached. I'm assuming that if you passed in a pageControl.currentPage value of 4 the app would crash.

Comment: Yeah, it would crash because of the force unwrapping of a failable initializer (`PageEnum(rawValue: currentPage)!`). There's probably some safer syntax to use but I don't currently know it off the top of my head.